# Java 8 Stream: Find first element after element

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this list `["z", "1", "3", "x", "y", "00", "x", "y", "4"]` that I need to get the first `Integer` element after the String `00` in this case `4`. I am using Java 8 streams but any other method is welcome. Here is my starter code

```
myList.stream()
      // Remove any non-Integer characters
      .filter((str) -> !"x".equals(str) && !"y".equals(str) && !"z".equals(str))
      .findFirst()
      .orElse("");
```

That starts me off by removing all non-Integer Strings but gives me `1`. Now what I need is to get `4` which is the first element after `00`. What should I add to the filter?

Comment: stream may not be proper to use in this case

Comment: @Lebecca I thought that will make my code neat and tidy :-). Anywhoo, lemmi look for another way

Comment: is "00" is fixed or changes ??

Comment: Why not just get indexOf "00" and use stream.skip(index).filter(str->isInteger(str)).findFirst()

Comment: @ThakkarDarshan If you mean position, well it can change position. But if you meant the actuall characters '00', no.

Comment: @beatrice lemmi try your proposal...

Comment: you can use `dropWhile` and continue using filter with Java-9+ as in `mylist.stream().dropWhile(s -> !s.equals("00")).filter...`, but what matters is the problem statement being specific about getting the integers and that too after a pattern `00`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got from the comment.

```java
 String result = myList.stream().skip(myList.indexOf("00") + 1)
        .filter((str) -> !"x".equals(str) && !"y".equals(str) && !"z".equals(str))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse("");
```

Comment: [somwhat like the `dropWhile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718818/java-8-stream-find-first-element-after-element?noredirect=1#comment107428430_60718818) suggestion I was making

Comment: This one worked. Thanks. Didn't think of the `skip()` method.

Comment: Since this is relying on the `List` API anyway, `myList.subList(myList.indexOf("00") + 1, myList.size()) .stream()` would be more efficient.

Comment: @Holger My initial intention came same with you. but using stream the whole process is kind of more `neat and tidy` as Kihats said as requirement in comments.

Answer (score 3):

A simple for loop, perhaps. A **lot** more readable then a stream expression, also more general, since strings like *'x'* and *'y'* are not hard coded into it.

```
boolean found00 = false;
int intAfter00 = -1;
for(String str: myList) {
    if("00".equals(str)) {
       found00 = true; //from this point we look for an integer
       continue;
    }
    if(found00) { //looking for an integer
       try {
           intAfter00 = Integer.parseInt(str);
       } catch(Exception e) {
          continue; //this was not an integer
       }
       break;
    }
}
//If intAfter00 is still -1 here then we did not found an integer after 00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("z", "1", "3", "x", "y", "00", "x", "y", "4");

        String str = "00";

        Optional<String> dataOptional = list.stream().skip(list.indexOf(str)+1).filter(s -> {
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(s);
                return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                return false;
            }
        }).findFirst();

        if (dataOptional.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Data is :: " + dataOptional.get());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No integer present after given string");
        }

    }
}
```

Make sure str is present in list otherwise it will return first integer from the list.

Comment: Actually, that's how I want it to work. If it can't find `00` then should return the first integer in the list

Comment: Great then.. You can use given code for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = myList.indexOf("00");
String result =myList.stream.skip(index).filter(str->isInteger(str)).findFirst().orElse(null);

private boolean isInteger(String str){
 try{
   Integer.parseInt(str);
   return true;
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   return false;
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows using `streams`:

```
String result=myList.subList(myList.indexOf("00")+1, myList.size()).stream().filter(string->string.matches("\\d+")).findFirst().get();
```

This solution gives you a good result even if you are using strings rather than `x`, `y`, `z`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the index of list at this moment. You could do something like this

```
int count = 0;

Stream.of("z", "1", "3", "x", "y", "00", "98", "y", "4")
.peek(element -> {
    if (element.equals("00") || count > 0 && isNumber(element))
        count++;
}).filter(element -> isNumber(element) && count == 3).findFirst().orElse(null);

private boolean isNumber(String element) {
    return element.matches("\\d+");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
Suppose you have a list

```
String[] v = {"z", "1", "3", "x", "y", "00", "x", "y", "4", "5", "y", "7"};
```

Now find first element after an element:

```
String result = Stream.of(v).filter(e-> e.matches("^(\\d+)")).dropWhile(e-> !e.contains("00")).skip(1).findFirst().orElse("");
System.out.println(result);
```